# Using sample and class weights in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to run a random forest on a highly unbalanced sample. There are issues both with the sample weights and the class weights. However, when I use the sklearn documentation to include the appropriate weights, I still get highly unbalanced predictions. For example, I have class weights of

`{'A': 0.05555555555555555, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 1.0}`

This should reweight the data to be about 60% A, 25% B, 15% C. However, when I run the model with weights, I get more or less the same results on the fitted class probabilities. I also tried doing the "balanced" option just to test, and I still got highly skewed results (predicting probabilities close to 1 for every observation of A). And I've tried this with and without the sample weights and with and without the class weights and I get more or less the same results. Am I implementing this incorrectly?

```
        clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,class_weight=class_weights)
        clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
        clf.fit(x,y,sample_weight=weights)

        print("Accuracy: ",metrics.accuracy_score(y, clf.predict(x)))

        new_arts = pd.DataFrame(data=clf.predict_proba(full_data_scaled),
                                columns=clf.classes_,
                                index=full_data_scaled.index.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you could check, is the actual dimensionality of your classifier in relation to your dataset. You use in both cases 1000 estimators. This can highly overfit if you are using a small dataset.

Second, I am assuming you use the Gini criterion to split. Maybe you can check if the criterion 'entropy' results in the same output.